# Filling a report from a stored procedure to an Access front end

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Assume this stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_MySP AS
  BEGIN
    SELECT a.Field1, a.Field2, v.Field3, p.Field4, a.Field5
    INTO #Temp1
    FROM tblMyTable1 AS a, tblMyTable2 AS p, tblMyTable3 AS v
    WHERE a.Field1 = p.Field1 
    AND a.Field1 = v.Field1 

    SELECT a.Field1, a.Field2, v.Field3, p.Field4, a.Field5
    INTO #Temp2
    FROM tblMyTable1 AS a, tblMyTable2 AS p, tblMyTable3 AS v
    WHERE a.Field1 = p.Field1 
    AND a.Field1 = v.Field1 

    SELECT *
    FROM #Temp1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT *
    FROM #Temp2

  END
```

And this vba code (I put the vba code on the LOAD event of the report):

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cnComments As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim strConn As String
    strConn = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATA SOURCE=WML202;INITIAL CATALOG=TOOL_TRACKING;UID=" & CVHx(SSTR1) & ";PWD=" & CVHx(SSTR2) & ";"
    cnComments.Open strConn

    Set rs = cnComments.Execute("EXEC sp_MySP")

    '** What do I do here?

End Sub
```

The actual stored procedure is much more complicated (and unnecessary) but that's the layout of the dataset.  It's a UNION ALL of a couple #Temp files.

How do I do the `'** What do I do here?` part so that the results of the stored procedure will fill the report?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Create a pass-through query which fetches data from the stored procedure and use the query as the report's Record Source.

Answer (score 2):

You could Set the Record Source of the form to a pass-through query that calls the stored procedure (similar as to how you would set it to the name of a table or query/view).

Then you could simply use data aware controls.